# Proving running time with induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

I need to use induction to prove the run time of the given recurrences:

$T(1) = c_1$

$T(n) = T(n-1) +  c_2$

Well this is the first time Im doing induction on this kind of exercise -
I would like just to get the idea of the structure of my induction (**Base** case , **assumption** ($k < n$) ? ,  induction **step** ($n = k$)?).

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you solve the recurrence equation completly first, sothat you have $T(n) = $ some term in $n$. Expand terms. You'll see that  $T(2) = c_1 + c_2$, $T(3) = c_1 + 2\cdot c_2$, ...

Comment: What do you mean by "prove the run time"? I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here. If it is to find a closed from for $T$, then that is easy enough as Maximilian Gerhardt indicates. It is just $T(n) = c_1 + (n-1)c_2$. Assume that formula holds for $n = 1$ (base case), and then show that if it holds for $n = k$, then it also holds for $n = k + 1$ (induction step).

Comment: Can u please write the Induction step? Im not sure how to prove this is = $O(n)$